# Restart Galaxy in SSH

Tags: ssh, restart, galaxy

I'm working with a SSH server, to run my Galaxy platform. Without using SSH, I can use my Galaxy website, so I think that Galaxy runs on deamon. Now I want to update my Galaxy files, and therefore I need to stop the Galaxy server and restart him.

My question is, how can I stop the Galaxy server, make an update en restart this server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running galaxy section in [this](http://www.agapow.net/science/bioinformatics/installing-galaxy) link, shall help you do it.

Please note that `/etc/init.d/galaxy` might already be existing on the server. If it already exists you can stop the server by writing:

> /etc/init.d/galaxy stop

and start it again by writing this on the console where you are logged into the server:

> /etc/init.d/galaxy start